# Highstock displayed data altered when navigator range is altered

Tags: highcharts

I am have noticed an issue with some of our highstock charts, though not all, where when the range selector at the bottom is altered it causes some of the data values to be change and displayed incorrectly.

For example a value of 4 becomes 2, 2 becomes 1, 1 becomes 0.5 etc.

I can use the tooltip value decimals option to make it display the values as only whole numbers as seen below however it still means the data is incorrect as the drawn line does not match the value, my jsfiddle example contains the area spline chart that has the issue where values change from incorrect values to correct values when the initial range is shortened.

http://jsfiddle.net/WNhmn/1/

```
                tooltip: {
                valueDecimals : 0
            },
```

Has anyone else run into this problem? Or have any idea as to why it is happening and how it can be stopped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by `dataGrouping`, set enabled: false, to prevent this, see: http://jsfiddle.net/WNhmn/2/

Comment: Ah many thanks Pawel, I thought it would have been something to do with the yAxis setting if anything as the data is used there but couldn't see anything in the api there for it.  Will remember this for use in the future and to check things like plotOptions.